# How to fix my Primefaces datatable pagination layout?

Tags: layout, primefaces, datatable, pagination

I use primefaces to display a list in a datatable with pagination.
The layout for the Page DropDown is not correct.

Screenshot:[image]

How can I set this layout?
It now stretches along the whole width of the table. This is not good.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{bean.lazyModel}" var="item"
             paginator="true"
             rows="10"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}
                {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink}
                {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,50,100"
             lazy="true"             
             selectionMode="single"
             selection="#{orderEntrySearchBacking.selected}"
             rowKey="#{item.id}">

    <f:facet name="header">
        Patients
        <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Columns"
            style="float:right" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
        <p:columnToggler datasource="dataTable" trigger="toggler" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.date}"/>
    </p:column>

    ....
```

This problem is related to the {RowsPerPageDropdown}, but I can't get the style correct. Help is appreciated.

That's all folks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `<select>` element has style `width: 100%`.
Inspect dropdown and find where style rule come from.
To fix it you should override this rule. One of the ways is to add following style rule to your .css file.

```
select.ui-paginator-rpp-options{
    width:auto;
}
```